# floating point division in C

Tags: c, math, types

I am writing a program that needs to do a bit of arithmetic.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    double h, x, n;
    printf("enter h > ");
    scanf("%1f", &h);
    printf("enter x > ");
    scanf("%1f", &x);
    /* here's where I believe I'm encountering an error */
    n = x/h;

    return 0;
}
```

so let's say I put in h = 0.01 with x = 0.25, I should get n = 0.25/0.01 = 25 right?

I've tried typecasting:

```
n = (float)x/(float)h;
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: Try `%lh` -- you're trying to read a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: PS always include headers for functions you use... `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: 1. You didn't show how you do the output. 2. There's plenty of questions related to non-expected outcome of float operations, try searching.

Comment: As mentioned, it's probably the `%f` not `%lf` tags to scanf.  However, you (after fixing that) you should post examples.  "Really weird" doesn't say much, but there are people on this board who can tell what went wrong just by glancing and output like that.

Comment: immediately returns NaN without prompting for user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably due to scanf. 
I suggest using fgets instead. 
But try:

```
int main(void){
    float h, x, n;
    printf("enter h > ");
    scanf("%f", &h);
    getchar();
    printf("enter x > ");
    getchar();
    scanf("%f", &x);

    n = x/h;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have written `%1f` (that's a digit one) in your scanf calls, but the right format for a double is `%lf` (that's a lower case L).

Consequently, your numbers aren't being converted properly to doubles, and you can't expect proper results.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have declared h,x,n to be a double and then assigned it to a float.try using float in the variable declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
float h, x, n;
printf("enter h > ");
scanf("%f", &h);
printf("enter x > ");
scanf("%f", &x);

n = x/h;
printf("%f",n);
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439410/floating-point-division-in-c#comment16726239_12439410). You need to specify the `l` modifier when attempting to read `double` input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline int flush() {
  return fflush(stdout);
}

int main() {
  double x, h, n;

  printf("enter h> ");
  flush();
  scanf("%lf", &h);

  printf("enter x> ");
  flush();
  scanf("%lf", &x);

  n = x / h;
  printf("n: %lf\n", n);
}
```